# How can I make an object appear in timeline at a certain frame?

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking, cloth-simulation, timeline

How can I add a specific object to my timeline at a certain frame?

I want to add a flag which should float over a pre-baked water fluid simulation. I baked a drop falling into water. After frame $120$, when the distortion becomes less turbulent, I want a flag to appear on its surface with a transparent text. But how can I tell the timeline that the flag object should start appearing at frame $120$ and that it shouldn't be influenced or be seen by physics before that time?

Answer (score 2):

Select your object (your flag in this case) then go to "object properties." Click on the "visibility" tab and click on "ray visibility." Turn off the check mark next to "camera." Hover your mouse over the empty checkbox and press <kbd>i</kbd> on your keyboard to add a keyframe. Once that's done, scrub through your timeline and find the timestamp where you want your flag to be shown and re-check the checkbox next to "camera" then press <kbd>i</kbd> to add another keyframe. It will be visible in object mode, but you won't see it when you render your animation. Let me know if this helped.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @[pinky-the-bat](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/92331/pinky-the-bat)'s answer, you can also keyframe the render. Select the flag object and go to keyframe $119$. Then in the Outliner, click the camera render icon to disable rendering and press <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering over that icon to create a new keyframe. Then go to frame $120$ and enable the camera render icon and press <kbd>i</kbd> again to create another keyframe. Now the flag object will only appear in the render output starting at frame $120$.

[image]