# Animation with fbx file

Tags: .fbx

I am new to Blender. I have a sequence of 3D hand poses in fbx file. All are in 5 files. They are sequences of open-close hand.
Question:
How can I make a video animation from these 5 fbx files?

Comment: import them all on the same spot then you could animate the `hide_render` property. its the camera icon in the outliner. you can press `i` while hovering over the icon. then click it to disable and press `i` again to animate hide it from render. do it with each object. such that they show and hide in sequence one after another

Comment: Thank you @HarryMcKenzie. When I pressed i, there were several options to select, which one should  I select?

Comment: no there are no options when u press `i` while hovering over the icon. here's an example how to animate the render property https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/272144/142292 take note though that u may still see the objects with `hide_render` set to True in viewport but they're not visible when actually rendering them.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, I followed your instructions but could not get the rendered animation.